# How do I backup system properly?

Tags: 12.04, backup

How do I backup my system so that if I do backup today, tomorrow when I recover it it's totally the same as yesterday?
I mostly care bout system itself, programs and documents are not that important but still would be nice to keep programs+settings for them.
I need it in case I do something dumb: purge needed package, mess up linux-headers, repository, tweak registry and fail and so on.

Examples:

- messed up with XConf and it's not working.
- used gconf-editor, did some changes and forgot where I did them, gconf-editor doesn't have undo or "don't save" feature, so I am wondering what the hell did I change?
  and so on.
- and so on, one more thousand stupid mistakes of a guy who is noob at Ubuntu but likes it and wants to become pro :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best way in the sense that you will copy everything, is to make a bit a bit image of your disk. This has the big disadvantage that, even if you zip it, it will take a lot of space.

Better than explaining this myself, check how to do it using "dd" in this link. http://www.backuphowto.info/linux-backup-hard-disk-clone-dd